# Date entered via VBA is not picked up and grouped as date by the autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, date, grouping, autofilter

So, i am using excel 2016.
I have a table with a date column.
I fill that table via VBA like so:

```
Dim DataTable As ListObject
Dim DataRow As Range

...

For Each Entry in Entries
DataTable.Resize DataTable.Range.Resize(DataTable.Range.Rows.Count + 1, DataTable.Range.Columns.Count)
Set DataRow = DataTable.ListRows(DataTable.ListRows.Count).Range
DataRow.Cells(1, 1).Value = Entry
DataRow.Cells(1, 1).NumberFormatLocal = "TT.MM.JJJJ"
DataRow.Cells(1, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
Next
```

'Entries' is a list of dates in string format.

Everything looked perfect, until i noticed that the column's autofilter won't group the dates added via VBA.
The Table has existing rows with dates added manually, those group correctly.
When i check the format of the added cells it is set to "TT.MM.JJJJ", like all other cells.
If i go in any one of the added cells and hit enter, that cell's value is then grouped correctly as well.

I am lost, what is wrong here, and how can i fix that within VBA :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution was rather simple after all,

The date can't be entered as plain string this way - i had to split it up and convert it via DateSerial function.